# Como troco um certificado HTTPS sem impactar em usuários antigos

Tags: https

Eu possuo um site que estava hospedado no firebase, com a opção para HTTPS ativa. Certo dia, decidi hospeda-lo numa revenda minha, com um certificado let's encrypt emitido para aquele domínio.

Nos novos dispositivos, não se teve nenhum comportamento estranho, porém nos que já haviam acessado o site sob o https, notificaram uma mensagem de erro de ssl. Ao limpar o cache a situação normaliza-se.

Existe algum modo de impedir esse erro SSL? A nova hospedagem me é vantajosa, porém não com erro de ssl para antigos usuários.

Comment: Acho que quem já entrou no site está acessando o HTTP e não o HTTPS, ai não encontra o protocolo e da erro. Não sei se da certo pq nunca tentei, mas vc pode tentar um Redirect 301 ou Canonical Tag para encaminhar quem entrar pelo HTTP para o HTTPS. Se quiser posso escrever uma resposta mais completa.

Comment: Então, o problema mora exatamente em quem já acessou o site através do HTTPS

Comment: Poderia informar qual é exatamente o erro que está ocorrendo?

Comment: Provavelmente você não instalou as CAs intermediárias, ai o certificado do Let's está usando coisa legada ou do cache. Verifique se pos a cadeia completa no servidor (o certificado do seu site da LE + intermediário geral da LE). Como configurar a cadeia completa, aí só lendo o manual do servidor HTTP usado. De qualquer maneira, essa não me parece uma pergunta sobre programação. Por ser de suporte, deveria ser feita no [sf] ou [su] em inglês.

Comment: Esse servidor está usando Apache ? Desculpe sou leigo com firebase

Comment: Usa apache. Ele cria uma proxy e aponta para uma porta de um servidor que roda node.js